# What is the origin of "Desilijic", Jabba's clan name?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, names, jabba-the-hutt

Is there an explanation for the origin of Jabba the Hutt's clan name? Namely, the Desilijic name, the full family name being Desilijic Tiure.

I know that the name Jabba has its roots in Indo-European (more precisely Balto-Slavic) languages. Desilijic is also spelled and written to mimic Indo-European (or more precisely Balto-Slavic).

**Is there a mention of the origin or story behind the clan name Desilijic?**

Comment: Just to clarify: you're asking about the out-of-universe origins?

Comment: @JasonBaker Well, since I'm asking about how the name was constructed or where it came from, then my answer must be yes.

Comment: I tried to dig up something, but there doesn't seem to be any explanation of what Desilijic means.  I'm guessing it's basically meaningless, and was chosen because it sounded cool.

Comment: @WadCheber Basically this is how it is, Ilijic and Silijic are real surnames. Without d, esilijic is part of a surname. And Desilijic could be a real surname. So, I'm asking how they came up with that.

Comment: @Secko - I couldn't find any information about why they chose this particular name.  It might be out there somewhere, but it doesn't seem to be on Wookieepedia or easily accessible sites.

Answer (score 1):

[Desilijic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Desilijic) is a Hutt *Kajidic*, a social structure meaning both family and crime gang.

[image]

Jabba, as head of his crime family, had the Desilijic's tattoo carved on his right arm. As to the origin, there is nothing in the [Huttese dictionary](http://www.completewermosguide.com/huttdictionary.html) that resembles or can compose the name. Since Huttese is based on Quecha, I looked up the word parts [here](https://glosbe.com/qu/en). For what it's worth, these are the closest I could find:

- Des: from, of
- Sila: picher or pot
- Jica: excrement